# Old token continues to receive messages targeting device with renewed, different token

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter application using Firebase messaging. I am currently using the following dependencies:

```
  firebase_auth: ^4.7.0
  firebase_core: ^2.15.0
  firebase_messaging: ^14.6.5
```

All my tests are currently done on Android.

My problem: my application continues to receive messages targeting old tokens, not the newest token I have retrieved either upon application start using `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()` or later obtained through `FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh` token update notifications.

Is this expected, or could this be a possible bug with Firebase Cloud Messaging?

In other words, when a particular device obtains a given token from the Firebase runtime

- does this mean that previously obtained (different) tokens for this device will never receive any message in the future, no matter what

OR

- Firebase Cloud Messaging may still send messages to that device with this old token if for some reason my server code still uses that old token

Thanks for your insight.